# Ad provider listener not working on Corona. ( Inner-Active)

Tags: ads, coronasdk

I'm using inner-active plugin with Corona 1137
I can show banner, text and fullscreen ads but these ads dont call my callback function.

What I want to do is to see if the user closed fullscreen ad and then immediately load a banner ad.

I use this code block:

```
function showAd( t )
    if t == "fsc" then
        print( "Ad call with fsc" )
        native.setActivityIndicator( true )
        ads.show( "fullscreen", { x = 0, y = 0, interval = 60, testMode = false } )
    elseif t == "n" then
        print( "Ad call with n" )
        ads.show( "banner", { x = 0, y = display.actualContentHeight - 48, interval = 30 }, 20 )
    else
        ads.hide()
    end
end
local function adListener( event )
    print( "Ad event : ", event )
    native.setActivityIndicator( false )
    if event.isError then
        print( "Failed to receive an add." )
    end
end

-- Inner-Active
ads.init( "inneractive", "*******ID********", adListener )
showAd( "n" )
```

Is there anything for me to check if the ad is closed? 
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

My name is Noga and I'm the Community Manager at Inneractive.
I invite you to visit Inneractive's developers wiki here: https://inneractive.jira.com/wiki/display/DevWiki/Home.
Most of the answers are already there.

If you still can't find the answer, please open a support ticket through your console and a Support Manager will contact you directly.

Good Luck!

Noga

Comment: Thanks for reply, I checked the link but I think my problem is related to Corona's ad library. Since Corona provide an ad library to developers, we cant reach inner-active listeners.